# Load songs from iPod Library right after sync

Tags: iphone, ipod, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I'm developing an iPhone application that uses the iPod library to play some songs. I load the songs with the code below. The problem is, when running this code right after the device has been synced with iTunes, there is a problem. Apparently the iPod Library needs to be updated, and it takes some time. If I go to the iPod Application right after a sync I seen a message saying "Updating Library..". If i call "[query items]" from my application while that is happening, I get an empty array indicating there is no songs in the library. Everything works perfect when the update is over. Is there any way to solve this problem? Maybe a way to detect when the update is over. I have tried to listen to alle NSNotifications, but none were called when the update finished.

```
    MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];

 // convert all items to abstracted media item
 NSArray *items = [query items];

 NSMutableArray *convertedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[items count]];
 for (MPMediaItem *item in items) {
  REMediaItem *mediaItem = [[REMediaItem alloc] initWithMediaItem:item];
  [convertedItems addObject:mediaItem];
  [mediaItem release];
 }
```

I hope someone can help.

Peter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I discovered that there actually is a way to see when the update is complete. The device will post a notification when the update is over.

```
[[MPMediaLibrary defaultMediaLibrary] beginGeneratingLibraryChangeNotifications]
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[notificationCenter addObserver:self 
                       selector:@selector(iPodLibraryDidChange)
                           name: MPMediaLibraryDidChangeNotification 
                         object:nil];
```

The only problem is that I can't find a way to determinate if the device is updating the iPod Library and I should wait for it to finish or the device simply doesnt have any songs in the library. [query items] will return an empty array in both cases.

Comment: I have the same problem actually right now - did you solve it anyhow?

Answer (score 4):

@Peter is right - and actually I found a walkaround for his problem.
At first I found that `MPMediaPickerController` returns `nil` when allocated and initiated while syncing - at first I thought it will work to check if there's an access to the library but sometimes it doesn't work.
The only way for now I found is to check `lastModificationDate` of `MPMediaLibrary` - as long as it's changing you won't get results using `MPMediaQuery` - delay your changes to a moment when that property stops changing (by any way you like) and you should be fine.
Already sent a bug report on that - the documentation says you should reload your cached objects from library when the notification fires but you clearly can't do it if `MPMediaQuery` returns `nil` for every object you try to find.

Comment: You have copied the answer from someone's post.

Comment: May be from this link http://www.wwml.tech/questions/192391/load-songs-from-ipod-library-right-after-sync